# What does $E_f (\log p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i)) = \int \log p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i)\,f(\tilde{y}_i)\,d\tilde{y}$ mean?

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm reading about Bayesian Data Analysis (by Gelman et al. 3rd edition, page 167-168) and there is one part I can't understand:

> *Predictive accuracy for a single data point*
>
> The ideal measure of a model’s fit would be its out-of-sample
>   predictive performance for new data produced from the true
>   data-generating process (external validation). We label $f$ as the
>   true model, $y$ as the observed data (thus, a single realization of
>   the dataset $y$ from the distribution $f(y)$), and $\tilde{y}$ as
>   future data or alternative datasets that could have been seen. The
>   out-of-sample predictive fit for a new data point $\tilde{y}_i$ using
>   logarithmic score is then,
>
> $$ \log p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i) = \log
>  E_{post}(p(\tilde{y}_i\,|\,\theta)) = \log \int
>  p(\tilde{y}_i\,|\,\theta)\, p_{post}(\theta)\,d\theta. $$
>
> In the above expression, $p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i)$ is the predictive
>   density for $\tilde{y}_i$ induced by the posterior distribution
>   $p_{post}(\theta)$. We have introduced the notation $p_{post}$ here to
>   represent the posterior distribution because our expressions will soon
>   become more complicated and it will be convenient to avoid explicitly
>   showing the conditioning of our inferences on the observed data $y$.
>   More generally, we use $p_{post}$ and $E_{post}$ to denote any
>   probability or expectation that averages over the posterior
>   distribution of $\theta$.
>
> *Averaging over the distribution of future data*
>
> We must then take one further step. The future data $\tilde{y}_i$
>   are themselves unknown and thus we define the expected out-of-sample
>   log predictive density, $$ \text{elpd} = \text{expected log predictive
>  density for a new data point}$$ $$
>  = E_f (\log p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i)) = \int \log p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i)\,f(\tilde{y}_i)\,d\tilde{y}.$$

What I don't understand is the last equation. What is $$E_f (\log p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i)) = \int \log p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i)\,f(\tilde{y}_i)\,d\tilde{y}?$$

What does $f(y)$ mean? This is confusing notation? Does $f(y)$ mean: "Distribution function which generated data $y$" or what?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to figure this out myself, could it be that the:

> $$  \text{elpd} = E_f (\log p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i)) = \int \log
>  p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i)\,f(\tilde{y}_i)\,d\tilde{y}$$

simply means that, given that on future we will observe some data $\tilde{y}$ with distribution $f$, then **on average** with respect to this future data the log predictive density for data point $\tilde{y}_i$  is $E_f (\log p_{post}(\tilde{y}_i))$.